# Cassandra update column

Tags: nosql, cassandra, phpcassa

how can i update column in cassandra database??

```
columnfam{
  username{
    name:edds,
    surname:surname,
    email:mymail@rrr.com
  }
}
```

for example i need update surname??

im using php client PHPCASSA.

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Octopus-Paul says, updates are the same as inserts.  There's no need to read before writing, though.  You can just do this:

```
$column_family->insert('username', array('surname' => $new_surname));
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here [cassandra-internals-writing](http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/03/13/cassandra-internals-writing/)
(Look at comments 14 and 15). I guess that if you retrieve data from your database, modify your data in PHP and reinsert that that back it will get updated (if your data has an UUID it will be updated - This is just an assumption -but give it a try)