# How to efficiently store this document structure in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to migrate this complex document structure to cassandra:

```
foo = {
  1: {
    :some => :data,
  },
  2: {
    :some => :data
  },

  ...

  99 :{
    :some => :data
  }

  'seen' => {1 => 1347682901, 2 => 1347682801}
}
```

The problem:
It has to be retrievable (readble) as one row/record in ~<5 milliseconds.

So far, I am serializing the data but that is not the optimum as I'm always in need to update the whole thing.

Another thing is, that I would like to use cassandras ttl feature for the values in the 'seen' hash.

Any ideas on how the sub-structures (1..n) could work in cassandra, as they are totally dynamic but should be readable all with one query?

Answer (score 3):

Create a columnFamily. And store as following

```
rowKey = foo

columnName           Value
-----------------------------------
1               {:some => :data,..}
2               {:some => :data,..}
...
...
99              {:some => :data,..}
seen            {1 => 1347682901, 2 => 1347682801}
```

1,2,... "seen" are all dynamic.

If you are worried about updating just one of these columns. It is same as how you insert a new column in a columnfamily. See here [Cassandra update column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699052/cassandra-update-column)

```
$column_family->insert('foo', array('42' => '{:some => :newdata,..}'));
```

I haven't had to use TTL yet. But it's as simple as it is. See pretty easy way to achieve this here [Expiring Columns in Cassandra 0.7+](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-expiring-columns)

---

**Update**

> **Q1.** Just for my understanding: Do you suggest creating 99 columns? Or is it possible to keep that dynamic?

Column family, unlike RDBMS, has flexible structure. You can have unlimited numbers of columns for a row key, dynamically created. For example:

```
myCcolumnFamily{
   "rowKey1": {
      "attr1": "some_values",
      "attr2": "other_value",
      "seen" : 823648223
   },
   "rowKey2": {
      "attr1": "some_values",
      "attr3": "other_value1",
      "attr5": "other_value2",
      "attr7": "other_value3",
      "attr9": "other_value4",
      "seen" : 823648223
   },
   "rowKey3": {
      "name"   : "naishe",
      "log"    : "s3://bucket42.aws.com/naishe/logs",
      "status" : "UNKNOWN",
      "place"  : "Varanasi"
   }
}
```

This is an old article, worth reading: [WTF is a SuperColumn?](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model) Here is a typical quote that will answer your query (emphasis mine):

> One thing I want to point out is that there’s no schema enforced at this `[ColumnFamily]` level. *The Rows do not have a predefined list of Columns that they contain.* In our example above you see that the row with the key “ieure” has Columns with names “age” and “gender” whereas the row identified by the key “phatduckk” doesn’t. It’s 100% flexible: *one Row may have 1,989 Columns whereas the other has 2. One Row may have a Column called “foo” whereas none of the rest do. This is the schemaless aspect of Cassandra.*

. . . .

> **Q2.** And you suggest serializing the sub-structure?

It's up to you. If you do not want to serialize, you probably should use SuperColumn. My rule of thumb is this. If the value in a column represents a unit whose parts cannot be accessed independently, use Column. (that means serialize value). If column is having fragmented subparts that possibly will require accessing directly use SuperColumn.

Comment: Just for my understanding: Do you suggest creating 99 columns? Or is it possible to keep that dynamic?
And you suggest serializing the sub-structure?

Comment: Thanks! I guess I would flatten down my structure to one level in a dynamic column family: seen: {1 => 1347682901, 2 => 1347682801} becomes seen_1: 1347682901, seen_2: 1347682801 etc. This makes it possible to set an independent ttl for each value. Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: yeah. more like `seen{foo:{1 => 1347682901, 2 => 1347682801}, bar:{1 => 1347682901, 2 => 1347682801}}` where 'seen' represents CF of, perhaps, users visit, 'foo', 'bar' are userIds, 1,2,3,..n represents columnName of nth visit and the values are timestamps. Makes sense to me.

Comment: hmmm, but if i put "seen" in another cf it's going to be a slower read, right? I mean I want to pull all the data with one request so it would be better to save it in one row?

Comment: @Tobias Forgive my mistake. I was confused that you wanted to store seen as a different CF in your previous comment. You were just posting snippet of columns in CF. so, yeah it makes sense `foo{"1":"{'somedata': 'val'},...", "2":"{'somedata': 'val'},...", ..., "seen_1": 1347682901, "seen_2": 1347682801, ... }`

Comment: Alternatively, instead of doing "seen_1", "seen_2", etc, use composite column names like `("seen", 1), ("seen", 2)`.

Comment: yeah, composite column is slick.